# Error in hybrid_segmentation HMError when running HTK

Tags: text-to-speech, cmusphinx, htk

HTS-2.3 and HTK-3.4.1 in my 64bit Ubuntu with gcc 3.4 compiler.

When I run the demo, HTK caused a problem:

error in hybrid_segmentation

Your help is highly appreciated.                 ^

> ```
> rm: No match.   ERROR [+3233]  DoAlignment: cannot align empty
> transcription  FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HVite rm: No match.
> rm: No match. cat: map_table: No such file or directory   ERROR
> [+5010]  SetScriptFile: Cannot open script file map_table   ERROR
> [+5020]  InitShell: SetScriptFile failed on file map_table   ERROR
> [+1000]  HCopy: InitShell failed  FATAL ERROR - Terminating program
> HCopy   ERROR [+2319]  HERest: data file name expected  FATAL ERROR -
> Terminating program HERest   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open
> source file hmm1/macros   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open
> file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm1/hmmdefs
> ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+7050] 
> LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected   ERROR [+2321]  Initialise:
> LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HERest   ERROR
> [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm2/macros   ERROR
> [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource:
> Cannot open source file hmm2/hmmdefs   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros:
> Can't open file   ERROR [+7050]  LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected  
> ERROR [+2321]  Initialise: LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR -
> Terminating program HERest   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open
> source file hmm3/macros   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open
> file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm3/hmmdefs
> ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+7050] 
> LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected   ERROR [+2321]  Initialise:
> LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HERest   ERROR
> [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm4/macros   ERROR
> [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource:
> Cannot open source file hmm4/hmmdefs   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros:
> Can't open file   ERROR [+7050]  LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected  
> ERROR [+2321]  Initialise: LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR -
> Terminating program HERest   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open
> source file hmm5/macros   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open
> file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm5/hmmdefs
> ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+7050] 
> LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected   ERROR [+2321]  Initialise:
> LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HERest   ERROR
> [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm6/macros   ERROR
> [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource:
> Cannot open source file hmm6/hmmdefs   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros:
> Can't open file   ERROR [+7050]  LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected  
> ERROR [+2321]  Initialise: LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR -
> Terminating program HERest   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open
> source file hmm7/macros   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open
> file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm7/hmmdefs
> ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+7050] 
> LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected   ERROR [+3228]  Initialise:
> LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HVite rm: No
> match. rm: No match. rm: cannot remove 'map_table': No such file or
> directory cat: map_table: No such file or directory   ERROR [+5010] 
> SetScriptFile: Cannot open script file map_table   ERROR [+5020] 
> InitShell: SetScriptFile failed on file map_table   ERROR [+1000] 
> HCopy: InitShell failed  FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HCopy cp:
> cannot stat 'hmm7/hmmdefs': No such file or directory cp: cannot stat
> 'hmm7/macros': No such file or directory   ERROR [+2319]  HERest: data
> file name expected  FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HERest   ERROR
> [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm1/macros   ERROR
> [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource:
> Cannot open source file hmm1/hmmdefs   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros:
> Can't open file   ERROR [+7050]  LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected  
> ERROR [+2321]  Initialise: LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR -
> Terminating program HERest   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open
> source file hmm2/macros   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open
> file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm2/hmmdefs
> ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+7050] 
> LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected   ERROR [+2321]  Initialise:
> LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HERest   ERROR
> [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm3/macros   ERROR
> [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource:
> Cannot open source file hmm3/hmmdefs   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros:
> Can't open file   ERROR [+7050]  LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected  
> ERROR [+2321]  Initialise: LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR -
> Terminating program HERest   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open
> source file hmm4/macros   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open
> file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm4/hmmdefs
> ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+7050] 
> LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected   ERROR [+2321]  Initialise:
> LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HERest   ERROR
> [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm5/macros   ERROR
> [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource:
> Cannot open source file hmm5/hmmdefs   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros:
> Can't open file   ERROR [+7050]  LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected  
> ERROR [+2321]  Initialise: LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR -
> Terminating program HERest   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open
> source file hmm6/macros   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open
> file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm6/hmmdefs
> ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+7050] 
> LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected   ERROR [+2321]  Initialise:
> LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HERest   ERROR
> [+3230]  HVite: Network must be specified for recognition from audio 
> FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HVite   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource:
> Cannot open source file hmm7/macros   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros:
> Can't open file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file
> hmm7/hmmdefs   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR
> [+7050]  LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected   ERROR [+3228]  Initialise:
> LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HVite cp: cannot
> stat 'hybrid_phone_lab/*': No such file or directory sed: can't read
> ../output_lab_phone/*: No such file or directory sed: can't read
> ../output_lab_phone/*: No such file or directory   ERROR [+5010] 
> InitSource: Cannot open source file hmm7/macros   ERROR [+7010] 
> LoadAllMacros: Can't open file   ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot
> open source file hmm7/hmmdefs   ERROR [+7010]  LoadAllMacros: Can't
> open file   ERROR [+7050]  LoadHMMSet: Macro name expected   ERROR
> [+3228]  Initialise: LoadHMMSet failed  FATAL ERROR - Terminating
> program HVite
> ```

Comment: I tried to fix your formatting somewhat, but it still isn't right. Do you think you could provide the original version, with the line-breaks in the right place? Except, this time, please ensure that you use code formatting instead of blockquote formatting so the line breaks are kept.

Unless this _was_ the original, in which case you're doomed. :-p This error is incomprehensible.

Comment: Now only i understand my problem actual problem in my data set.   ERROR [+3233]  DoAlignment: cannot align empty
transcription  FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HVite rm: No match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a case of missing files. Are you sure you've set the PWD (present working directory) to what the build guide says it should be, and are you sure you have all the files?

Comment: i already set pwd. ./usr/local/HTS-2.3/bin$ ls
Cluster  HCopy        HDMan   HInit  HLMCopy    HMGenS    HParse  HResults  HSMMAlign  LAdapt  LGCopy  LLink    LNorm
HBuild   HDecode      HERest  HLEd   HLRescore  HMgeTool  HQuant  HSGen     HSmooth    LBuild  LGList  LMerge   LPlex
HCompV   HDecode.mod  HHEd    HList  HLStats    HMMIRest  HRest   HSLab     HVite      LFoF    LGPrep  LNewMap  LSubset

Comment: @kumar Who knows, then? It'd be good if you linked to the thing you're trying to compile; I can't find it easily online.